# Swift optimisation performance clarification

Tags: ios, swift

After seeing the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgK8jaf8nlk), i got confused about the use of final keyword.

Here below is an example image from the video

[image]

Here there are two classes Pet as parent class and Dog as child class, and we have function implementation of makeNoise(p) which takes Pet instance as parameter. But behind the scene compiler inserts few more lines to this method for checking class.

Since makeNoise(p) takes parameter as Pet instance, compiler should directly call the property "name" from the Pet class, as the method parameter is for this class.

Why would compiler be worried about the overriding the property in child class, because the parameter is a Pet instance and compiler knows it. isn't it?

My question may looks silly but if someone can explain it more clearly, i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of `makeNoise(p: Pet)` must be a `Pet`, but it does not to be an immediate instance of `Pet` itself. Since `Dog` is a subclass of `Pet`, it is also a `Pet`. Therefore, in Swift it is perfectly valid for someone to pass a `Dog` instance into `makeNoise`, in which case the overridden version of `noise` will be called. Also, this dog may have chosen a different value for `name`.

### Dynamic Type

This is called the 'dynamic type' of `p`. The compile-time type of `p` is `Pet`, but the compiler must account for the fact that the run-time type of `p` might be a `Pet` subclass that overrides something. This is called the 'dynamic type' of `p`. In Swift 1 and 2, which were in use at the time of WWDC 2015, use the `.dynamicType` syntax on an object to determine its runtime type. Swift 3 uses the `type(of: object)` global function. This is not something you'll need very often, but it demonstrates how the compiler allows subclasses to act as their parent and still override things.

### `final`

`final` tells the compiler that either the class will not be subclassed, or the property or method will not be overridden. This way it won't need to check for overrides.

### Changes in Swift 3

This year's WWDC 2016 session on Swift performance did not mention the `final` keyword once, if I remember correctly, however. While it is still available in Swift 3 and serves the same purpose, there are new ways to prevent subclassing and overriding. This is via Access Control. Swift 3 introduces the `open` keyword as distinct from `public`.

- `public` – The object, property, method, etc. is accessible by anyone inside or outside the module
- `open` – The class or method is not only accessible by anyone, but may also be subclassed (in the case of classes) or overridden (in the case of methods).

I am not sure if this, like `final`, communicates to the Swift compiler that it does not need to do its extra type checking.